# How to find an angle (in degrees) in a right triangle, given its sides?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I need to find out a degree of an angle. Pretty simple, or so I thought. I remember doing a crap-ton of these in high-school, sadly the details did not remain.

Anyway, let's take a look at this triangle.

[image: Triangle]

Let's say the angle I want to find out is D. Well, I decide to use sin and assume

```
sin(D) = 3 / 5
D = asin(0.6) 
D = 64 rad ???

cos(D) = 3/4
D = acos(0.75)
D = 72 rad ???
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious and stupid here. Can't figure out what that is...

Thanks!

Comment: $\cos$ is adjacent over hypotenuse

Comment: You got the first one right, it’s $.64350$ radians. But the formula for cosine is adjacent-over-hypotenuse. The opposite-over-adjacent is the tangent formula. Don’t forget that *one* radian is a big angle just less than sixty degrees.

Comment: Please try to come up with more descriptive titles in the future. (See: [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion here between radians and degrees. $\arcsin(3/5) = 0.643$ radians. But radians are not the same as degrees. You can convert from radians to degrees by multiplying by $\frac{180}{\pi}$.

Here, this gives that $0.643$ radians is the same as about $36.8^\circ$ (and we would get the exact answer if I hadn't truncated to $0.643$ in my calculation).

(And as the others have pointed out, your cosine calculation uses the wrong two legs of the triangle).

Comment: Oh, thanks. For some reason I've thought that radians are the same as degrees. That makes sense now, thanks.

Comment: @user3279266: no problem. It's commonly overlooked. Depending on what you're learning trig for, you may want to get to know radians better. If you're learning calculus, for example, radians are more useful.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that $\cos(D)=\dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}=\dfrac{4}{5}$ instead of $\cos(D)=\dfrac{3}{4}$. It is the tangent of $D$ which is $\dfrac{3}{4}$.

Note that in your picture you are using degrees, while the calculations have been in radians.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got your question right but if you want to translate radiants to degrees you can use this formular: $$\frac{\alpha}{360°}=\frac{r}{2\pi}$$

So in your case $r = 0.64$ and thus $\alpha = 36.67°$

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that cosine = adjacent/hypotenuse. Your trig rules:

sine = opposite/hypotenuse

cosine = adjacent/hypotenuse

tangent = sine/cosine = opposite/adjacent